# Binding on ImageSource is not showing in ImageBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm generating bitmaps in the Code and want to display it on the GUI. But the `<ImageBrush>` is not showing them as `BitmapSource/ImageSource`. Just like as an invisible image in the 3D part.
On the `<Image>` (not the 3D part) it shows as wanted.

I also tried to create the `DiffuseMaterial` and `ImageBrush` in the codebehind and bind them directly into `<h:RectangleVisual3D>` as `Material`.
And tried to use `<VisualBrush>` instead of `<ImageBrush>` with `<Image>` as child in XAML.

The following Code reproduce the issue for my case:

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="WPF3DTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF3DTest"
        xmlns:h="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <h:HelixViewport3D Grid.Row="0">
            <h:DefaultLights />
            <h:RectangleVisual3D Length="100" Width="100">
                <h:RectangleVisual3D.Material>
                    <DiffuseMaterial>
                        <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            <ImageBrush Opacity="1" ImageSource="{Binding Image}" />
                        </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                    </DiffuseMaterial>
                </h:RectangleVisual3D.Material>
            </h:RectangleVisual3D>
        </h:HelixViewport3D>
        <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Image}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
namespace WPF3DTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ImageSource Image { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

            Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\TypenschildDirectory\\Graphic\\laufrichtung2.png"));
            Image.Freeze();
        }
    }
}
```

The `new BitmapImage(new Uri(...))` is a test in my case. But for my purpose it's generated bitmaps by using `Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(...)`.

Comment: `Image` needs to be a dependency property, so it will notify the binding in the XAML when its value changes, so that the binding will know when to update the target property. Note that `DataContext = this` is relatively harmless on a Window as you have here, but bad practice in UserControls, because it will break any other bindings. So it's better to get in the habit of using RelativeSource bindings instead.

Comment: In my real application the exemplary `Image` is in a ViewModel with NotifyPropertyChanged. Registering dependency property in a ViewModel?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to help you diagnose issues in code you haven't shown me. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if it's the correct answer but it solved my problem.
Providing a "DataProxy"/"BindingProxy" solved the binding for the `<ImageBrush>`.

As far I understand from this link https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/ is that the `<ImageBrush>` does not has inherited the DataContext.

```xml
<h:HelixViewport3D.Resources>
    <wpf:BindingProxy x:Key="ImageProxy" Data="{Binding Image}" />
</h:HelixViewport3D.Resources>
...
<ImageBrush Opacity="1" ImageSource="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource ImageProxy}}" />
```